# Postcode / Address finder

Tags: mysql, geolocation, geocoding, postal-code

Like a lot of people I would like the Post Office PAF file for Postcode to Address data. What I have at the minute is the Postcode to O/S coordinates file. Are there any solutions for getting this type of data ? Could I rip any credible data from a sat nav postcode file ?

Comment: Which country?......... *puts on magic hat*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source which I use is Yahoo Geo Planet.

You can download the entire GeoPlanet Data file which comes in TSV format. 
When I downloaded it I just imported it to mysql using mysqlimport.

http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/geoplanet/data/

It contains a record for every distinct geographically location in the world. A tonne of post codes, (pretty much every code I have needed for UK). 
All you would need to do is only use records with are of `place_type` zip.

## Example

**Click** https://i.stack.imgur.com/1l2Yc.png

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For New Zealand data, your best bet is to use the official NZ Post’s [Postal Address File (PAF)](https://www.nzpost.co.nz/business/sending-within-nz/quality-addressing/postal-address-file-paf) and Land Information New Zealand (LINZ) for [street address files](https://data.linz.govt.nz/layer/53353-nz-street-address/) with latitude and longitude geo coordinates.  If you prefer programming with SOAP or REST APIs then an [Address Finder Search API](https://www.addy.co.nz/address-finder-and-postcode-api) combined with the [Geocode Address API](https://www.addy.co.nz/address-reverse-geocoding-api) would help for bulk reverse lookups.